# JSON import from another file contains undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `data.js` containing placeholder data.

Here is `data.js` :

```js
export const FOO = {
  "prop": "example", 
  "sample":[OB1, OB2, OB3]
}

export const OB1 = {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"bar"
}

export const OB2 = {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"buzz"
}

export const OB3 = {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"bing"
}

console.log(FOO);
```

I'm trying to import `FOO` in another file

```
import {FOO} from './data.js'
```

But when I log the value of `sample` I get `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Now I know that the variable reference is probably missing ?

What could be the solution to access `FOO` with `OB` values and not just variable.

Comment: `const` and assignments are not hoisted. Declare (and export) `FOO` *after* declaring the `OB`s.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Right! Thank you.

Comment: Actually, the script shouldn't have run in the first place, I think. `ReferenceError: OB1 is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence of specifying the export is incorrect

```
export const OB1 = {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"bar"
}

export const OB2 = {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"buzz"
}

export const OB3 = {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"bing"
}

export const FOO = {
  "prop": "example", 
  "sample":[OB1, OB2, OB3]
}
```

`const FOO` should be exported at the end so that it can use the value of `OB1`, `OB1` and `OB3`. Then you will not get `undefined` for that array.

Answer (score 0):

A more decent way to do this would be to import `data.js` first and then reference `FOO`

**Example**

```
//in your new file declare data like this
var _data = require('../data');

//then call FOO
_data.FOO;

//or print it to console like this
var display = _data.FOO;
console.log(display);
```